# How to make multiple API calls using ConcatMap with conditions

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular7

In Angular 7, I am trying to invoke two different API methods sequentially. If first one is successful then need to call second API method.

If first API response code is 500 internal server error then second API should not be invoked. Also I need to handle errors for each API calls.

I tried Promise, async and await approach but when I check in developer tools, could see second one is invoked even if first API does not return any response.

Can someone please help me to achieve this using concatmap or any other Angular approach.

```
public fetchandUpdate() {
    this.isSuccess= false;
    this.errorMessage = "";
    this.displayMessage = false;

     // First API call
      this.myService.getUserDetails(this.userid)
      .subscribe(
        (response) => {                           
          console.log('response received')
          this.userdetails= response;
        },
        (error) => {                              
          console.error('error caught in fetching user details')
          this.errorMessage = error;
          this.isSuccess= false;
        }
      )

    // Need to call this only if first API's response http status code is not 500
   if(firstAPIresponse.statuscode != 500)
   {
    this.myService.updateUserDetails(this.userdetails)
          .subscribe(
            (response) => {                           
              console.log('response received')
              this.isSuccess= true;
            },
            (error) => {                              
              console.error('error caught in updating user details')
              this.errorMessage = error;
              this.isSuccess= false;
            }
          )
      

     // This value should be updated only if above two is successful
      this.displayMessage=true;
    }
  }
```

Comment: You might want to try piping through a switchMap or alternatively convert to promise and await them. Currently you are running the calls in parallel and so there is no opportunity to use the data from the first nor make it conditionally execute

Comment: @Michael Can you please share any sample URL for this scenario.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `switchMap` to accomplish this.

```
// First API call
this.myService.getUserDetails(this.userid).pipe(
  // Logging is a side effect, so use tap for that
  tap(res => console.log('First API success', res)),
  // Call the second if first succeeds
  switchMap(resultFromUserDetails => this.myService.updateUserDetails(this.userdetails).pipe(
    // Handle your error for second call, return of(val) if succeeds or throwError() if you can't handle it here
    catchError(err => { 
      console.log('Error for second API (you can use statusCode here)', err);
      return of(); 
    }),
    // Logging is a side effect, so use tap for that
    tap(res => console.log('Second API success', res)),
  )),
  
  // Handle your error for first call, return of(val) if succeeds or throwError() if you can't handle it here
  catchError(err => { 
    console.log('Error for first API (you can use statusCode here)', err);
    return of(); 
  }) 
).subscribe(
  // handle both successfull
  resultFromUpdateUserDetails => {
    console.log('Both APIs succeeded, result from 2) is returned', resultFromUpdateUserDetails);
  },
  // handle uncaught errors
  err => {
    console.log('Any error NOT handled in catchError() or if you returned a throwError() instead of of() inside your catchError(), err);
  } 
)
```

**Update**: You can, of course, do some logic inside your `switchMap`

```
this.myService.getUserDetails(this.userid).pipe(
   switchMap(res => {
     // do something with res, or other logic here

     // make sure to return your new observable at the end
     return this.myService.updateUserDetails(this.userdetails);
   })
);
```

Comment: I could not understand error handing section. Can you please update the answer with console.log('error') or (console.log('success') for each section. It would be very helpful.

Comment: Also, Is it possible to use if logic before switchMap.

Comment: Also where I can check Internal Server Error status code from First API response.

Comment: Updated my answer. Yes, it is possible to use logic inside your switchMap. Just make sure to return a new observable at the end. You can check the errorCode inside your catchError(). It is getting the same error you would get inside your second callback in subscribe.